# How to remove a character from a string

Tags: javascript, node.js

I need to delete a # in a url for example I have the string:

```
message:  hello http://www.google.it#readme
```

and I must delete '#' character. This is my code in node.js:

```
messagge.replace(new RegExp(/((http|https)\S*#\S*)+/g),function(x){
                    x.replace('#','');
                    console.log(x);

            });
```

The console prints the link but the link is not change is: http://www.google.it#readme. Anyone can help to find a solution?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assign the replacement to x:

```
messagge.replace(new RegExp(/((http|https)\S*#\S*)+/g),function(x){
                    x = x.replace(new RegExp(/#/g),'');
                    console.log(x);

            });
```

Answer (score 1):

Use it like this to eliminate all the '#' in your link.

```
x = x.replace(/\#/g,'');
```

or like this to eliminate just one:

```
x = x.replace('#','');
```